# use a sprite png in li-class and display in div

Tags: css, html, styles, html-lists

I have some problem with displaying a sprite in a div that is in a `li` class.

So the structure is:

```
<li id="aa">
    <div><a href="#">one</a></div>
</li>
```

And the CSS:

```
li{
        width: 120px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
li div{
        width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image:url(../images/sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

When I use this I can see the sprite even outside the div. So I tried adding this to `li`:

> background-image: none;

That makes the image in the div not visible too.

So if there is someone who know about that I really would appreciate.

Comment: you forgot a ";" after background-image?

Comment: cant you style <a> instead of styling div btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing a `;` after background-image please see below

`background-image:url(../images/sprite.png);`

Comment: @bonny I've made up a fiddle with your above code but I can see the image http://jsfiddle.net/jcrTE/ Is it possible the image path is wrong? Or the position of the image?

Comment: hello and thanks for answering this question. it was a combination of both. missing ; plus missing background-image: none.